# Why does my regex group quantifier not work?

Tags: php, regex, quantifiers

I try to write some regex for Dutch license plates (kentekens), [the documentation](https://www.rdw.nl/Particulier/Paginas/Uitleg-over-de-cijfers-en-letters-op-de-kentekenplaat.aspx) is very clear and I only want to check them on format, not if the actual alpha character is possible for now.

[My regex (regex101)](https://www.regex101.com/r/rILtsk/1) looks as follows:

> `(([0-9]{1,2}|[a-z]{1,3})-([0-9]{2,3}|[a-z]{2,3})-([0-9]{1,2}|[a-z]{1,2})){8}/gi`

However this returns no matched, while

> `([0-9]{1,2}|[a-z]{1,3})-([0-9]{2,3}|[a-z]{2,3})-([0-9]{1,2}|[a-z]{1,2}/gi`

does

However I **do** like to check the total length as well.

**JS Demo snippet**

```js
const regex = /([0-9]{1,2}|[a-z]{1,3})-([0-9]{2,3}|[a-z]{2,3})-([0-9]{1,2}|[a-z]{1,2})/gi;
const str = `XX-99-99
2​ 1965​ 99-99-XX ​
3​ 1973​ 99-XX-99​
4​ 1978​ XX-99-XX ​
5​ 1991​ XX-XX-99 ​
6​ 1999​ 99-XX-XX ​
7​ 2005​ 99-XXX-9​
8​ 2009​ 9-XXX-99​
9​ 2006​ XX-999-X ​
10​ 2008​ X-999-XX ​
​11 ​2015 ​XXX-99-X`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: PHP or javascript?

Comment: @chris85 project is PHP, but to quickly show the problem I included a js demo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `{8}` quantifier added at the end will act on previous expression, in this case the whole regex, because it is enclosed with parenthesis. [See here](https://www.regex101.com/r/0p5fOC/1) what matches this regex.

To test for length, use this regex [`(?=^.{1,8}$)(([0-9]{1,2}|[a-z]{1,3})-([0-9]{2,3}|[a-z]{2,3})-([0-9]{1,2}|[a-z]{1,2}))`](https://www.regex101.com/r/ohrsJc/2) It uses a lookahead to make sure that the following characters match `^.{1,8}$`, which means the whole string should contain between 1 and 8 character, you can adjust it to your needs.